Output file has not been built from source file - Vite + TS
Issue:
Output file '/home/some_path/vite.config.d.ts' has not been built from source file '/home/some_path/vite.config.ts'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Matched by include pattern '**/*.ts' in '/home/some_path/tsconfig.json'

Tech-Stack:
Typescript - 5.3.3,
Vite,
React - 18
Required Data:

tsconfig.json

      {
          "compilerOptions": {
            "baseUrl": ".",
            "target": "es5",
            "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
            "strict": true,
            "noEmit": true,
            "allowJs": true,
            "module": "esnext",
            "jsx": "react-jsx",
            "skipLibCheck": true,
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "noImplicitThis": true,
            "esModuleInterop": true,
            "isolatedModules": true,
            "strictNullChecks": true,
            "resolveJsonModule": true,
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
            "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
            "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
          },
          "exclude": ["node_modules"],
          "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "src/**/*"],
          "references": [
            {
              "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
            }
          ]
        }


tsconfig.node.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "vite.config.ts"
  ]
}


package.json(scripts)

"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "start": "vite preview",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "rm:all": "rm -rf node_modules .next out dist build",
    "re:start": "yarn rm:all && yarn install && yarn dev",
    "re:build": "yarn rm:all && yarn install && yarn build",
    "re:build-npm": "npm run rm:all && npm install && npm run build",
    "dev:host": "vite --host"
  },

Description:
I have tried to solve this error from a quite a while now and I do not understand the root cause of it. This issue is present in this platform in other variants but any of the mentioned solution in them is not working for me. I have tried and changes the tsconfig and also tsconfig.node. I have also tried manipulating my global TS version but it also did not help. I have also tried to apply the -b switch for the build time but nothing works. Any of the solution when applied generates more and unexpected TS errors in the project which are totally un-related.
If you are reading this question I request you to not close/report it immediately as duplicate but extend some help for the same as the provided solutions are not working for me.
